# Reinstall conda and packages from scratch

Tags: anaconda, conda

I have my conda corrupted due to pip install.
After manipulations, I end up having 2 Python 2.7 interprete in the same conda root env.....

I have other conda env. safe and intact.
How to re-isntall the default root env in a clean way ?
I have exported the packages by :

```
conda list --explicit > spec-file.txt   
conda create --name myenv --file spec-file.txt     # Create Env using a file
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution :

1) reinstall minconda in a new folder
   2) Remove duplicates in spec-file.txt
   2) create new conda env using the spec-file.txt

Cleaner and better way I found....
(also backing up the conda folder is also a good solution)

Answer (score 0):

Here are instructions build your Conda environment from the scratch.

To see what Conda environments you have:

```
conda env list
```

Remove your environment by name:

```
conda deactivate
conda env remove -n $myenv
```

Then create it again:

```
conda create -n $myenv
conda activate $myenv
```

Then proceed to reinstall all packages.